# Software updating programs builtin to macOS Big Sur

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, software-update, big-sur

What software updating programs are builtin to macOS Big Sur?

I already know about the following GUI applications:

- App Store
- Software Update (GUI for Software Update)

I already know about the following Terminal executables:

- `/usr/bin/cpan`* (e.g., `cpan`, `cpan5.18`, etc.)
- `/usr/bin/gem`
- `/usr/bin/pip3`
- `/usr/sbin/softwareupdate` (Terminal executable for Software Update)

What additional software that is builtin to macOS can be run to update software?

To get pedantic, let's consider as a builtin software updating program any file in a fresh Big Sur install whose path can eventually be made to point to a file that that is a software updating program through a process that the original file at that path somehow mentions or actuates. e.g., the initial file at `/usr/bin/pip3` isn't a pip3 executable; it only outputs instructions about how to change that path (`/usr/bin/pip3`) to point to an actual pip3 executable.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118826/discussion-on-question-by-xdr-software-updating-programs-builtin-to-macos-big-su).

Answer (score 3):

There is no mechanism in macOS to keep all software up to date.  So you need to consider other mechanisms.

My list:

- Obviously the Apple App Store.
- [Mac Updater](https://www.corecode.io/macupdater/) alerts me (and helps install) updates to nearly all the apps I have installed.  This is the biggest improvement to app updating I have come across for a long time.
- To check on the state of Apple macOS updates (particularly firmware,
  Gatekeeper, XProtect, etc.) I find [Silent Knight](https://eclecticlight.co/lockrattler-systhist/) to be invaluable. It obviates the need to manually run `/usr/sbin/softwareupdate`.
- Users of HomeBrew (package manager for Unix/Linux apps) will use `brew update`.  And users of other package managers will need to use their update methods.
- Adobe users find it hard to avoid the Adobe (Creative Cloud) updater - it is somewhat intrusive in my view.

Answer (score 1):

macOS is designed to prompt users to update as needed. Most users do not need to manually update their system or included software. See Apple's [How to update the software on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201541) for authoritative advice:

> Use Software Update to find and install updates for macOS, built-in apps like Safari, and apps downloaded from the App Store.

To further simplify applying updates, Apple recommends enabling **Automatically keep my Mac up to date.** in the Software Update settings.